# Babel, use Symbol without polyfill

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I am using Babel 6 with the `babel-preset-es2015` preset.

When the code is transpiled, it includes in it references to `Symbol`s, which aren't supported in Node <= `v0.12.0`.

```
    throw _iteratorError;

ReferenceError: Symbol is not defined
```

When I google this, I keep seeing that I need the Babel polyfill.

It's huge. I don't want it. I simply want Babel to transpile *everything* to straight ES5.

What am I missing?

Comment: Symbol is one new keyword for ES6, I am afraid it cannot be transpiled to ES5..

Comment: But then why would the `babel-preset-es2015` *create* it? I didn't use a Symbol. It transpiled my code to it.

Comment: Good question, I'm looking for an answer to this too...